# Stuck validating nested Object Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I'm trying to add validation on the child entity, i.e. OrderItem.
To do so I've added @Valid annotation on the Order.ListOfOrderItems but it is not working.

Below is the code snippet of Order, OrderItems and OrderController.

Order.java

```
@Entity
@Getter @Setter
@Table(name = "orders")
public class Order extends BaseEntity {
    protected @NotBlank String customerId;

    @Valid @NotNull
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "order")
    private List<OrderItems> orderItems = new ArrayList<OrderItems>();

}
```

OrderItems.java

```
@Entity
@Getter @Setter
public class OrderItems extends BaseEntity {
    protected @NotNull int productId;
    protected @NotNull int quantity;

    @Getter(AccessLevel.NONE)
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "order_id", nullable = false)
    private Order order;
}
```

OrderController.java

```
@PostMapping("/order/")
public Order saveOrder(@Valid @RequestBody Order order) {
    return orderService.save(order);
}
```

POST order/

```
{
    "customerId": "asdhajhdjssga",
    "orderItems": [
        {
            "productId": 1,
            "quantity": 2,
        },
        {
            "productId": 2,
            "quantity": 2,
        }
    ]
}
```

How do I validate the child object?

Comment: `@NotNull` on an `int` field is pretty much useless... `int` default value is `0`. The `@NotNull` annotation is only useful for types that can be `null` and a primitive cannot be `null` by design. Either use `@Min` to specify the minimal value, or use an `Integer` instead of `int`.

Comment: Yes got it. Worked after changing `int` to `Integer`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you have annotated a primitive field, type `int`, with `@NotNull`. A primitive field can never be `null`and thus the `@NotNull` will never kick in, as the default value is 0.

Either change the `int` to `Integer`, which is the object wrapper which can be `null` or use something like `@Min` to validate a certain value.